# Events calendar with clickable days using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, calendar

I'm about to create a solution that will list events that will occur in specific days, and was looking for a Calendar control that I can deal with to make only the days with events clickable, and of course receive this click event and handle the rest myself in my Controller.
(something like the old asp:Calendar server-side control in Webforms).

is there any that match this scenario?

**Update:** What I'm exactly looking for is a Mini Calendar, not a full Calendar like the one in Outlook.

this is what I'm exactly looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery UI can do the exact styling you want.. (*and functionality*)

You will need to download the ***jQuery UI*** script and the ***Smoothness*** theme  <sup>(*visit http://jqueryui.com/download/ and select **core** and **datepicker** from the radio buttons, and smoothness from the drop-down to the right*)</sup>

**html**

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

**javascript**

```
var activeDays=[1,4,10,21,22,23,27,28,30];

$('#datepicker').datepicker(
    {
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var hilight = [false,''];

            if ( activeDays.indexOf( date.getDate() ) > -1)
            {
                hilight = [true,'isActive'];
            }

            return hilight;
        }
    }
);
```

The `activeDays` variable could hold dates directly (*instead of just the day number*) and you would need to alter the conditional inside the function to check for a match.

The `isActive` is a class used to control the styling of the active dates..

```
.isActive a.ui-state-default{
    background:none;
    background-color:pink;
}
```

**Live example at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/C95nx/2/

the above code and example renders as

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I made something like this a couple of years ago by heavily modifying a javascript calendar called [MooTools Event Calendar](http://dansnetwork.com/mootools/events-calendar/)

There are several other javascript calendars that look pretty good as well. 
These 2 use JQuery:

- [Full Calendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)
- [Web-Delicious Events Calendar and Planner](http://www.web-delicious.com/jquery-events-calendar-wdcalendar/tp://)

Comment: Really appreciate your effor, but this is not exactly what I'm in need to. I've updated my question with a sample image to show exactly the mini calendar I'm in need to have. or simply click this link: http://i51.tinypic.com/2jb5rp1.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You can use jquery UI datepicker along with the `beforeShowDay` event to customize which days are selectable and which days are not. Here is the minimal code which disables selecting the date 5 and you can extend the logic.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
           if(date.getDate() == 5){
                return[false, ''];           
           }
           else{
               return[true, ''];
           }
       }
    });
});
```

Here's a quick [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aWVzQ/)

Answer (score 2):

Many people use the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). I'm not sure of a built in asp.net mvc control for the calendar.

Comment: Thank you, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for, Can you check this image for extra details : http://i51.tinypic.com/2jb5rp1.jpg

Answer (score 2):

If you can still use Javascript in your code, take this control and customize its UI. It has source code available for your own customization requirements.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/eventscalendar.shtml#

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is beyond late as an answer, but your question is quite high up in Google results, so hopefully it will help other people. I wrote an article on this very topic here:
[Datepicker based MVC3 Events Calendar](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/321268.aspx?q=MVC3%20Content%20Action%20REsult)

Answer (score 0):

[How to limit days available in jquery ui date-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389743/how-to-limit-days-available-in-jquery-ui-date-picker)

or

http://test.thecodecentral.com/cms/jqueryui/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate MVC with silverlight and use silverlight calendar 
http://developerstyle.posterous.com/silverlight-calendar-with-mvc-3

Answer (score 0):

In order to complement @gaby-aka-g-petrioli's answer I included `onChangeMonthYear` and `onSelect` methods that allows get click actions.

```
$("#my_datepicker_calendar").datepicker({
    dateFormat : 'm/d/yy',  // month/day/year
    changeMonth : true,
    changeYear : true,
    beforeShowDay : function(date)
    {
        var mm = date.getMonth() + 1, dd = date.getDate(), yy = date.getFullYear();
        var dt = mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yy;
        if ( typeof selectedDates[dt] != 'undefined' ) {
            return [true, "", selectedDates[dt].content];
        }
        return [false, ""];
    },
    onChangeMonthYear : function(year, month)
    {
        alert('Month selected is ' + month + ' and year is ' + year);
    },
    onSelect : function(date)
    {
        var date = date.split("/");
        alert('Date selected is ' + date[0] + '/' + date[1] + '/' + date[2] + '.');
    }
});
```