# jquery calendar to choose a date and filter events based on the chosen date

Tags: jquery, date, calendar

I need something like this:
 [Events calendar with clickable days using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607869/events-calendar-with-clickable-days-using-jquery-in-asp-net-mvc3)

and I have been able to implement sth close. What I would like to get some help is how do I make the active dates dynamic? like  make only those dates active that have events. In my case , each event is an aspx page with event details like date, time, location, map etc..to be more specific, this is sharepoint publishing site, each page is a publishing page using some custom layout with custom fields.. anyways, based on the dates on those pages, i need to be able to make the dates active..Can someone give some idea?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the datpicker [beforeshow](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-beforeShow) event and enable restrictions inroder to disable/activate specific dates