# Enable only dates that are in the array

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have just started using jQuery UI's datepicker and I am looking for a way to enable dates that are only in the data array... I tried everything but it doesn't seem to disable any dates. I checked data array and it display everything in the following format if I use `console.log(data)`:

*`["2017-04-28", "2017-05-19", "2017-04-03", "2017-04-05", "2017-04-07", "2017-04-04", "2017-04-12"]`*

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/getDoctorsAppointments/'+doctor_id+'/',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success:function(data) {
       // enable only dates in the "data" array
    }
});
```

Any ideas how I can achieve that **only** dates in the array are enabled/can be selected in the datepicker?

Comment: This is a duplicate question, and you should indeed consult the above answers. I would offer though that your case is only complicated by being asynchronous. I would suggest using the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/389743/how-to-limit-days-available-in-jquery-ui-date-picker and checking against a promise returned by your ajax call.

Comment: @RafaelKennedy I'm still struggling to understand where my Ajax call should go... And how to get that ajax response as a variable into another function? it just doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Sure. I would construct a new promise: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: Sure, I haven't tried it, but this is what I would do:
`var list = new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
  $.ajax({..., 
    success: function(data){
      resolve(data)
    },
    error: function(e){
      reject(e)
    }
  })
})

list.then((array) => {
  $('input').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
      var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
      return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
  });
})
 `